# My code wont print out the correct value for the array index 0

Tags: arrays, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

```
#include <NewPing.h>

#define SONAR_NUM 6      // Number of sensors.
#define MAX_DISTANCE 500 // Maximum distance (in cm) to ping.

NewPing sonar[SONAR_NUM] =     // Sensor object array. Each sensor's trigger pin, echo pin, and max distance to ping.
{
  NewPing(1, 2, MAX_DISTANCE),   //1 Bottom right
  NewPing(3, 4, MAX_DISTANCE),   //2 Top right
  NewPing(5, 6, MAX_DISTANCE),   //3 Bottom middle
  NewPing(7, 8, MAX_DISTANCE),   //4 Top middle
  NewPing(9, 10, MAX_DISTANCE),  //5 Bottom left
  NewPing(11, 12, MAX_DISTANCE), //6 Top left
};

int Dist;
int myDist[6];
int m;
int minIndex;
int minValue;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200); // Open serial monitor at 115200 baud to see ping results.
  }

void loop()
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SONAR_NUM; i++)   // Loop through each sensor and store results.
  {
    delay(30); // Wait 30ms between pings . 29ms should be the shortest delay between pings.
    myDist[i] = sonar[i].ping_cm(); 
  }
  math();       //go to math function
}

void math()
{
    int minIndex;
    int myDist_length = sizeof(myDist) / sizeof(myDist[0]);        //find length of array
    int minValue = myDist[minIndex];                              //min value = value from min index of array
    for(byte j = 1; j < myDist_length; j++){                     //for loop lasts length of array
    if(myDist[j] < minValue) {                                  //if loop finds out if value is smaller than previous smallest
        minValue = myDist[j];
        minIndex = j;
    }
}
//Serial.print(minValue);
//Serial.print(", ");
Serial.print(myDist[0]);
Serial.println();

}
```

My code is attempting to find values from ultrasonic sensors and store them in an array. It works fine, except my first sensor wont print out a value when I attempt to print the 0 index of the array. Ive used another code and the sensor is functional as well as the wiring. My guess is the way im storing it is wrong. All the other indexs of my array print out the appropriate value from the correct sensor but number 1 or index 0 doesn't.

Comment: Why j start from 1 instead of j=0?

Answer (score 0):

What is the output do you get for **`index 0`**?
Is it always the same number, for example, `0`? Or, is it a random number? Always positive? Just trying to help you debug.

Comment: Its always 0, the other indexs relays the correct number

Comment: I don’t remember if Arduino initializes the array elements to 0. I’d like to know where the 0 in your data is coming from - polling data from sensor or just initialized and never overwritten. Can you manually set the [0] value to some unlikely number like 1111 and see if it remains as that even after the sensor is polled?

Answer (score 0):

In the math() function:

int minIndex;

Should be

```
int minIndex = 0;
```

You need to give minIndex an initial value.  You are assuming that it starts off as zero.  That is not a safe assumption since it is a local variable.  You need to set it explicitly to zero.

Comment: I also notice that you have a global variable with the same name.  It would have started off with a value of zero, but you shadowed it and never used it.  It's generally not smart to have more than one variable in scope with the same name.  That causes all types of confusion.  Either get rid of the global one or the local one.